# How do I solve these audio issues?

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa, realtek

I finally took the plunge and installed the latest Pop_OS on my home computer. Windows is gone. However, I am having a few bad issues with the sound configuration.

My computer is set up for recording and streaming gaming content. On Windows, I was able to use the Realtek HD Audio Drivers and the Sound Manager software that came with it to monitor my mic input through my speakers/headphones so I can hear myself talk. This is very important since I use noise isolating headphones.

Pop_OS, being an Ubuntu based distro, comes with Pulse Audio and Pulse comes with a module called loopback. There are two issues with this. 1: This seems to loop back the mic input into the desktop audio channel with software instead of using the hardware solution on my motherboard. On my Windows system, the microphone input was spliced perfectly into the speaker/headphone output WITHOUT actually having that mic audio be part of the desktop audio stream. I was able to record desktop audio separately from mic audio. If I record desktop audio here on Pop_OS, my voice will be part of the desktop channel AND the mic channel.

2: The looped back audio just sounds weird. It sounds as if my voice is layered on top of itself multiple times and maybe even delayed by just a few milliseconds (despite me using latency_msec=1). I think this comes down to the same issue as the above since it uses software instead of properly talking to the hardware.

These are my main issues now. I'm open to finally buying a sound card that's supported well on linux if that's what it takes. Also, keep in mind that I'm a complete noob and by no means a sound engineer, so my interpretations of what's actually happening might be way off.

Anyway, I appreciate anyone's help. Thank you.

-Saylor